# C# EWS in Exchange AutodiscoverUrl Exception while using Version 2010 or latest

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

a had successful connection with ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1, when I changed it on 2010 or latest I get the exception on this row:

service.AutodiscoverUrl(MailboxToAccess, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
->System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
I tried with Packages:
Exchange.WebServices.Managed.Api v2.2.1.2 and Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices v2.2.0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String MailboxToAccess = "username@domain";
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
            SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false);

            service.Credentials = new WebCredential("username@domain", "password");
            service.AutodiscoverUrl(MailboxToAccess, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            SetStreamingNotifications(service);
        }
```

```
 private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
        {
            bool result = false;

            Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
            if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I set the Exchange service URL manually using

```
/ Create the binding.
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
// Set the credentials for the on-premises server.
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user1@contoso.com", "password");
// Set the URL.
service.Url = new Uri("https://computername.domain.contoso.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

I still don't understand why It didn't work for me with

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl("User1@contoso.com");
```